# Swift/iOS - Save Image with given aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, aspect-ratio

I have been searching on the web for a few hours now trying to look for a solution but to no luck.

I have read a few topics already made and taken the suggestions, but to no look.

I have installed the `CropViewController` pod in my project and the image/image preview has the aspect ratio 9:16 which is perfect. The issue is when I wish to save this image to the users photo library. It's just the same/normal aspect ratio `Original`.

This is my code. I have the camera functions in one view controller and the presenting and saving of the image in another view controller.

```
import UIKit
import CropViewController

class CameraPreviewController: UIViewController {
    var image: UIImage!
    @IBOutlet var imagePreview: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
              imagePreview.image = image
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func saveButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        let croppedImage: UIImage = self.image
        let cropViewController = CropViewController(image: croppedImage)
        cropViewController.customAspectRatio = CGSize(width: 9.0, height: 16.0)
        self.image = croppedImage
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
}
```

How can I save the image as is on screen? I have tried but to no luck. The image is 9:16 but the issue arises when saving. How can I overcome this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to save the image with origin size?

Comment: @YuraPetrov I wish to save the image with the aspect ratio 9:16, like how you save pictures with snapchat.

Comment: okay, I'll try to help you. Do know how get a photo from gallery or take a photo with your app?

Comment: @YuraPetrov Yes, my app allows for images to be either taken or selected from the users gallery.

Answer (score 0):

You should add "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description" to info.plist.
Try this method, I hope this will help you if that doesn't help, I'll be trying to find another way.

```
func cropViewController(_ cropViewController: CropViewController, didCropToImage image: UIImage, withRect cropRect: CGRect, angle: Int) {
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I believe I have found the solution. However, I will try yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Changed this line of code -

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
```

to the following:

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = .iFrame1280x720
```